# rails3, Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a problem with devise. When user already signed in, and then clicks on sign in link, nothing happens, but here is output in my terminal:

```
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
```

This happens when i'm going to `Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML`

Is there any way, how i can tell devise to go to `after_sign_in_path` if there is logged user?

here is my after_sign_in_path

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if session[:user_return_to]
      return_to = session[:user_return_to]
      session[:user_return_to] = nil
      return_to
    else
      redirect_path(resource)
    end
end
```

Comment: Check to see if there are any errors firing in the sign in or sign up controller. I had this issue once and I fixed it after whitelisting a Model parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should consider to prepend a filter before in the controller?

```
prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [:action1, :action2]
```

Comment: do you mean to add this line to a subclass of Devise::SessionsController or to actually modify the source of devise? I'm not sure how this actually works in the first case, and the second case sounds like a bad approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if (return_to = session[:user_return_to])
      session[:user_return_to] = nil
      return_to
      return
    else
      redirect_path(resource)
    end
end
```

I don't sure this is working
but maybe use can use after_filter